# create HTTPClient in Titanium

Tags: titanium

I have used Ti.Network.createHTTPClient in Titanium and see that the control goes neither inside onLoad nor onError. What could be the reason?

```
 var loader = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
       loader.onload = function() { 
      alert("Hello");   
        }  
      loader.onError = function(e) 
        alert("Error: " + e.error);
     }
```

Comment: You did not send the request.

Comment: Also, you forget to open : loader.open ..

Comment: Hi dosth try with this link it may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056587/titanium-httpclient-returns-too-fast?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Add these 2 lines to make it work! You did not send the request, nor did you send the URL

```
// add url in here 
loader.open("GET",'[URL HERE]'); 
// Send the request.
loader.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xhrSitelogin = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhrSitelogin.open('POST', webservice_url);
xhrSitelogin.send({
method : "userlogin",
username : username,
password : password
});
xhrSitelogin.setTimeout(10000);

xhrSitelogin.onerror = function() {
showAlertBox('Service timed out. Please try again.');
//Hide Indicator
};
xhrSitelogin.onload = function() {

  alert(this.responseText);
   //RESPONSE RECEIVED
};
```

Vote Up or mark best if you consider it help full.

Answer (score 0):

Hi dosth try with this am not sure it will work if it work i will be happy

var taskRequest = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

```
    var api_url = 'http://myawesomeapi.heroku.com/users/' +
```

Ti.App.Properties.getString("userID") + '/tasks';

```
    taskRequest.onload = function() {

        var tasks = [];

        // code populating the tasks array

        alert(tasks);

        callback( tasks ); // invoke the callback
    }

    taskRequest.open('GET', api_url, false);

    taskRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    taskRequest.send();
```

<....>

Answer (score 0):

```
loader.open("POST/GET","URL");
loader.onload(response){
//get the response
console.log(this.responseText);

};
loader.send();
 Use this pattern.
```

If you need to set any header then use `loader.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");` after the `open()`/before `onload()` and `send()`