# Alloy MVC Framework Titanium Network (Model)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm trying to authenticate using the Model in Alloy. I have been trying to figure this problem out since yesterday. If anybody could help me, I'd really appreciate it.
So, I have a view `login.xml`, then a controller `login.js`. The `login.js` contains the following function:

```
var user = Alloy.Models.user; //my user.js model
function login(e) {
    if($.username.value !== '' && $.password.value !== ''){
        if(user.login($.username.value, $.password.value)){
            Alloy.createController('home').getView().open();
            $.login.close();
        }
    }else{
        alert('Username and/or Password required!');
    }
}
```

Then in my `user.js` model, it's like this:

```
extendModel : function(Model) {
    _.extend(Model.prototype, {
        login: function(username, password) {
            var first_name, last_name, email;
            var _this = this;
            var url = 'http://myurl.com/test.php';
            var auth = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
                onerror: function(e){
                    alert(e.error);
                },
                onload: function(){
                    var json = this.responseText;
                    var response = JSON.parse(json);
                    if(response.logged == true){
                        first_name = response.f_name;
                        last_name = response.l_name;
                        email = response.email;
                        _this.set({
                            loggedIn: 1,
                            username: email,
                            realname: first_name + ' ' + last_name,
                            email: email,
                        });
                        _this.save();
                    }else{
                        alert(response.message);
                    }
                },
            });

            auth.open('POST', url);
            var params = {
                usernames: username,
                passwords: password,
            };
            auth.send(params);
            alert(_this.get('email')); //alert email
        },
    });
```

When I click on login in `login.xml` it calls the function `login` in `index.js`. So, now my problem is that, when I click the button for the first time, I get an empty alert from `alert(_this.get('email'))`, but then when I click the button the second time, everything works fine, it alerts the email. I have no idea what's going on. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out, for people that might stumble upon the same problem. I used callback function to do it.

Refer to this [Titanium HTTP Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056587/titanium-httpclient-returns-too-fast)

Now my `user.js` looks like this:

```
extendModel : function(Model) {
_.extend(Model.prototype, {
    login: function(username, password, callback) {
        var first_name, last_name, email;
        var _this = this;
        var url = 'http://myurl.com/test.php';
        var auth = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
            onerror: function(e){
                alert(e.error);
            },
            onload: function(){
                var json = this.responseText;
                var response = JSON.parse(json);
                if(response.logged == true){
                    first_name = response.f_name;
                    last_name = response.l_name;
                    email = response.email;
                    _this.set({
                        loggedIn: 1,
                        username: email,
                        realname: first_name + ' ' + last_name,
                        email: email,
                    });
                    _this.save();
                    callback(foo); //whatever you want to send

                }else{
                    alert(response.message);
                }
            },
        });

        auth.open('POST', url);
        var params = {
            usernames: username,
            passwords: password,
        };
        auth.send(params);
    },
});
```

And my `login.js` looks like this:

```
var user = Alloy.Models.user; //my user.js model
function login(e) {
    if($.username.value !== '' && $.password.value !== ''){
        var logged_in = user.login($.username.value, $.password.value, function(foo){
            if(foo == bar)
                call_another_function(); 
        });
    }else{
       alert('Username and/or Password required!');
   }
}
```

Thanks. I hope this helps.

Comment: this code is still incorrect... you should always execute the callback.. you are not executing it on error conditions

Comment: @AaronSaunders why should the callback be executed on `onerror`? I would assume you would handle an `onerror` differently than in the callback. I suppose if the error login lived in the callback that would be fine, but I'd rather separate the two functions

Comment: @Ronnie i would assume the caller would want to know that an error happened so it can be handled properly?

Comment: @AaronSaunders I am thinking that the callback is for success and onerror is to handle the error. I am transitioning from classic to alloy so I am trying to figure out Alloy models since last week. Slowly making progress

Comment: Thanks @AaronSaunders. I added the callback on the error. Sorry for the late reply!